# Which pairs of parts of speech are allowed and not allowed in grammatically correct sentences?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I found the names of the 9 parts of speech in
Korean from here: [Parts of Speech](https://jojal-jojalkorean.tumblr.com/post/187041713847/english-has-8-parts-of-speech-korean-has-9)

Which word pairs can be found in grammatically correct sentences? I made the text bold if I thought it was allowed and italic if I thought it wasn't.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **명사 명사** | **대명사 명사** | *수사 명사* | 동사 명사 | 형용사 명사 | 관형사 명사 | 부사 명사 | 조사 명사 | 감탄사 명사 |
| *명사 대명사* | *대명사 대명사* | *수사 대명사* | 동사 대명사 | 형용사 대명사 | 관형사 대명사 | 부사 대명사 | 조사 대명사 | 감탄사 대명사 |
| 명사 수사 | 대명사 수사 | 수사 수사 | 동사 수사 | 형용사 수사 | 관형사 수사 | 부사 수사 | 조사 수사 | 감탄사 수사 |
| 명사 동사 | 대명사 동사 | 수사 동사 | 동사 동사 | 형용사 동사 | 관형사 동사 | 부사 동사 | 조사 동사 | 감탄사 동사 |
| 명사 형용사 | 대명사 형용사 | 수사 형용사 | 동사 형용사 | 형용사 형용사 | 관형사 형용사 | 부사 형용사 | 조사 형용사 | 감탄사 형용사 |
| 명사 관형사 | 대명사 관형사 | 수사 관형사 | 동사 관형사 | 형용사 관형사 | 관형사 관형사 | 부사 관형사 | 조사 관형사 | 감탄사 관형사 |
| 명사 부사 | 대명사 부사 | 수사 부사 | 동사 부사 | 형용사 부사 | 관형사 부사 | *부사 부사* | 조사 부사 | 감탄사 부사 |
| **명사 조사** | **대명사 조사** | **수사 조사** | 동사 조사 | 형용사 조사 | 관형사 조사 | 부사 조사 | 조사 조사 | 감탄사 조사 |
| 명사 감탄사 | 대명사 감탄사 | 수사 감탄사 | 동사 감탄사 | 형용사 감탄사 | 관형사 감탄사 | 부사 감탄사 | 조사 감탄사 | 감탄사 감탄사 |

Comment: Could you please provide examples for the bold and the italic?

Comment: And a typo: the column #5 only has “형용사 명사.”

Comment: @КонстантинВан I changed column 5. Examples for not allowed in English would be "cat blue", and something that would be allowed would be "blue cat"

Answer (score 1):

### 관형사 & 명사

“첫째” is a 수 관형사<sub>numeral determiner</sub> here.

- “**첫째 딸**”: the firstborn among the daughters, not necessarily the firstborn.

---

### 명사 & 명사

- “**접근 금지 구역**”

---

### 동사 & 명사

- “**뛰는 노루**”

---

### 동사 & 대명사

- “**웃는 그**”

---

### 형용사 & 대명사

- “**으스스한 그곳**”

---

### 형용사 & 명사

- “**으스스한 장소**”

---

### 관형사 & 대명사

- Impossible

---

### 명사 & 조사

- “**동물의**”

---

### 대명사 & 조사

- “**그의**”

---

### 명사 & 수사

- “**사과 다섯**”

Answer (score 1):

수사 명사 - 아메리카노 **셋, 카페라테** 둘 주세요. "Can I have three Americanos and two Caffe Lattes, please?"

명사 대명사 - 내가 먹고 싶은 것은 바로 **랍스터 그것**이다. "What I want to eat is lobster."

대명사 대명사 - **너 나** 좋아해? "Do you like me?"

수사 대명사 - 아메리카노 **셋, 이거** 둘 주세요. "Can I have three Americanos and two of these, please?"

부사 부사 - 이 기계가 작동이 **잘 안** 된다. "This machine doesn't work very well."

Comment: Is "랍스터 그것" natural? I feel like something should interrupt it; the interruption would be written by a punctuation like **랍스터 — 그것** or **랍스터! 그것**.

Comment: Just as @DannyuNDos said. The 랍스터 is not modifying 그것 in your example "랍스터 그것."